# How to unify the orientation of the faces in a mesh?

Tags: faces

I was using *Tissue* to tessellate a mesh but the orientation of the faces is not unified, I already tried to recalculate, smooth the normals, or explode and rejoin the faces but it doesn't align.

I tried to correct it in Grasshopper by meshOrientation and imported it in Blender again, so far it works but is there a way to do it directly in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Chris, .. can you share a couple of small failing examples on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can be reasonably sure we're fixing them?